# Xcode 8: Type 'UserDefaults' has no member 'standard'

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to get UserDefaults working in Xcode8/Swift 3, but keep getting the following error:

Type 'UserDefaults' has no member 'standard'

My code:

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set("value", forKey: "myKey")
```

Comment: That code compiles without errors in my Xcode 8. Did you define another UserDefaults type somewhere in your project?

Comment: One of my colleagues had a similar issue, it solved by re-downloading the xcode.

Comment: I did not define another UserDefaults in my project, also I got the same code in another project where it compiles without errors... I will try re-downloading xcode

Comment: If you cmd-click on `UserDefaults` in Xcode, what does it show you?

Comment: try `UserDefaults.standard()`. If that works, you are using Swift 2.

Comment: I just found out that there is indeed a custom UserDefault type defined inside my project. Pretty sure I didn't add it myself, was propably one of my colleagues. Stupid mistake by me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add namespace to fix it:

```
let defaults = Foundation.UserDefaults.standard
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue. I have created a class "UserDefaults" in my project. When I have changed the class name to different name, it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5 Xcode v12.4

My class was required to inherit from NSObject in order to use the UserDefault methods.

```
class UserDefaults: NSObject, ... {
   
   //methods would not pop up without NSObject inheritance
   UserDefaults.standard.set( ect....)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Clear the Derived Data of XCode
xcode->preferences->locations->derice